# C-language binary Math - Convert bytes to hex and to decimal

Tags: binary, number-systems

I am having concerns on a homework assignment.

> All problems are in **C-Language Syntax** (*<--What does that imply? Am I supposed to write my answers in a certain format?*)
>
> 1. Given two bytes x=`0x23` and y=`0xA2`, fill in the following table indicating the byte values of the different C expressions: (**ONE BYTE
>      ANSWERS**) (*<--What does that imply? What is a "one-byte" answer?*)
>
> ```
>  -------------------------------------------- 
> | Expression    Hex Value    Decimal Value   |
> |   x & y                                    |
> |  ~x | y                                    |
> | !x || y                                    |
> | x && ~y                                    | 
>  --------------------------------------------
> ```

I have looked up the binary equivalencies of `0x23` and `0xA2`. I found that:

`0x23`=`0010 0011`=23=x

and

`0xA2`=`1010 0010`=162=y

I know that the `&` symbol is the AND operator and `|` is the OR operator. Knowing this, I ANDed the binary values of x and y together to find x & y:

```
x:     0010 0011
y:     1010 0010
x & y: 0010 0010
```

`0010 0010`=`0x22`=34=x & y

...and OR'd the vaues of ~x and y together to find ~x | y:

```
~x:     1101 1100
y:      1010 0010
~x | y: 1111 1110
```

`1111 1110`=`0xfe`=254=~x | y

Are those correct?

I asked an online tutor to assist me, and he got the following results:

```
 -------------------------------------------
| Expression    Hex Value    Decimal Value  |
|   x & y         0022          34          |
|  ~x | y       ffff fffe       -2          |
| !x || y          0001          1          |
| x && ~y          0001          1          |
 -------------------------------------------
```

How did he get -2 as the decimal value for ~x | y? Is getting negative values even possible? Also, are his hex values formatted correctly? In the instructions, it says to give "**ONE BYTE ANSWERS**". Doesn't that mean they should be formatted like they are in the question? (i.e. `0x23` and `0xA2`).

Finally, that leaves the `&&` and `||` operators. On [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/), it says that `&&` and `||` are "logic operators", while `&` and `|` are bitwise operators. I'm not sure what that means or how to apply that to the evaluation of the binary expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "C-Language Syntax", the problem presumably means that all the symbols are to be interpreted as given in the C standard. This helps to clarify, for example, the distinction between `|` and `||`.

You're right, the first row is `0x22 = 34` and the second row is `0xfe`. There are two ways to interpret `0xfe`, either as a `uint8_t`, in which case its decimal value is `254`, or an `int8_t`, in which case its decimal value is `-2`. The problem is ambiguous! It describes the data types of `x` and `y` as simply "bytes". I think you're justified in assuming an unsigned type, so your `254` is correct. If possible, I would explicitly write this assumption in your homework. You can even mention that `-2` is the other option, just to cover your bases in case the grader makes the opposite assumption.

`0xfffffffe` is incorrect because it occupies 4 bytes, which violates the "ONE BYTE ANSWERS" part of the question.

As for the logical operators, their behavior is not something that you can divine from mathematical principles; it really depends on how C represents booleans as integers, which is not universal among programming languages. Your class really ought to cover that stuff!

Answer (score -1):

First, in your example, ~x|y=0xffff fffe instead of 0xfe -- the leading 1's make all the difference.

Are you familiar with the two's complement representation of numbers? Basically, 0xffff ffff is -1 in decimal. 0xffff fffe is 1 less than 0xffff ffff and is therefore -2.

Read more about two's complement here:
https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

Regarding && and ||. C treats non-zero integers as True (1) and zero as False (0). So !x || y becomes (not True) OR True which evaluates to True (1).

Since y is non-zero, ~y is non-zero too. So x && ~y becomes True AND True which evaluates to True(1).

Comment: Alright...Interesting...Never heard of Two's Complement. Why does it apply here? How did we evaluate `0xffff fffe` to be the hex equivalent of `~x | y` in the first place? As seen above, I evaluated `~x|y`=`0xfe`=254. I don't know why that's wrong. I used the same style of logic to get that answer as I did with my evaluation of `x & y`, which the tutor's answer agrees with. I don't know why I'm supposed to smack on 7 additional leading `f`'s and treat it as a "two's complement" hex value.